# File native distribution doesn't open shell in compose for Windows

Tags: windows, powershell, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-multiplatform

I'm developing an Windows app running resource file .cmd as administrator. When I run source code, there is no problem. But when I run executed package by command `./gradlew run`, my app cannot run resource file.

Here is the function that do it:

```
fun openFile() : Boolean {
    val resource = Any::class::class.java.getResource("/Script_Kich_hoat_Windows_va_Office_Online_6_thang.cmd")
    if (resource != null) {
        val command = arrayOf("powershell", "\"", "start", resource.toString(), "-v", "runAs", "\"")
        val runtime = Runtime.getRuntime()
        runtime.exec(command)
        return true
    }
    return false
}
```

Here is source file `build.grade.kts`:

```
import org.jetbrains.compose.desktop.application.dsl.TargetFormat

plugins {
    kotlin("jvm")
    id("org.jetbrains.compose")
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven("https://maven.pkg.jetbrains.space/public/p/compose/dev")
    google()
}

dependencies {
    implementation(compose.desktop.currentOs)
}

compose.desktop {
    application {
        mainClass = "MainKt"

        nativeDistributions {
            targetFormats(TargetFormat.Dmg, TargetFormat.Msi, TargetFormat.Deb, TargetFormat.Exe)
            packageName = "KotlinJvmComposeDesktopApplication"
            packageVersion = "1.0.0"
            windows {
                packageVersion = "1.0.0"
                msiPackageVersion = "1.0.0"
                exePackageVersion = "1.0.0"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried with `ProcessBuilder` and `Desktop.getDesktop.open()` but they didn't work well.